# Schedule will not select if the date and time is already pasted

Tags: mysql

Hi guys can you help me about this one...

i just want to not select all of the date and time that already pasted... I'm using join table

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM pgs_schedule LEFT JOIN pgs_schedule_versus ON pgs_schedule_versus.pgs_schedule_id = pgs_schedule.pgs_schedule_id WHERE date(pgs_schedule_versus.schedule_time) > CURTIME() AND date(pgs_schedule.schedule_date) > CURDATE() ORDER BY schedule_date DESC, schedule_time ASC
```

pgs_schedule table:

```
    +---------------------+
    | schedule_date       |
    +---------------------+
    |2017-03-06           |
    |2017-03-07           |
    |2017-02-07           |
    +---------------------+
```

pgs_schedule_versus table:

```
+---------------------+
| schedule_time       |
+---------------------+
|15:00:00             |
|16:00:00             |
|16:00:00             |
+---------------------+
```

the march will show but the feb will not be selected...
but if the march 6, 2017 will be selected and the time is already pasted it will show march 7...

Comment: why don't you use `NOW()` instead of `CURTIME()` and `CURDATE()`

Comment: I tried it.. but its not working.. hmm... the March 6 3PM on wards data is still not showing

Comment: i just want to show the upcoming schedule. also if the schedule is today and time is still not exact at the database.. the code will still show it on the page... but if the date is today and time is already pasted... the code will not select it...

Comment: could you please show table data and structure

Comment: okay i'll edit my question

Comment: Clearly that is a misrepresentation of both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your mysql query :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pgs_schedule s
  LEFT 
  JOIN pgs_schedule_versus v
    ON v.pgs_schedule_id = s.pgs_schedule_id 
 WHERE CONCAT(s.schedule_date,' ',v.schedule_time) > NOW() 
 ORDER 
    BY schedule_date DESC
     , schedule_time ASC
```

Concat date and time then compare with `NOW()`.

To get the exact value of `NOW()`, run the following query :

```
SELECT NOW()
```